# reading until the end of file in C++

Tags: c++, file

I'm trying to read till the end of a file for a phonebook app that im converting from C to C++. When I print the the results from the file i get this:

```
johnny smith
(Home)3
(Cell)4
x☺> x☺>
(Home)4
(Cell)4
```

it should print:

```
johnny smith
(Home)3
(Cell)4
```

Right now I'm using `while(!infile.eof())` which i've read is a poor practice, but when I use `infile.getline()` I get a repeat of the first and last name, and the format is all jacked up. Is there anyway(or another way) to get rid of the junk at the end of the input or another way to read till the end of file in C++ that fixes this. I've been reading about different solutions, but the one a lot of sites seem to agree on is `fgets`, which is what I had with the original C version, but obviously `fgets` doesn't work with `ifstream` which is what I'm using. here is the code:

```
void contacts:: readfile(contacts*friends ,int* counter, int i,char buffer[],char    user_entry3[])
{
   ifstream read;
   read.open(user_entry3,ios::in);
   int len;
   contacts temp;
   *counter=0;
   i=0; 

     while (!read.eof()) { 
       temp.First_Name=(char*)malloc(36); 
       temp.Last_Name=(char*)malloc(36); 

       read>>temp.First_Name>>temp.Last_Name;

       read>>buffer;
       len=strlen(buffer);
       if(buffer[len-1]=='\n')
          buffer[len-1]='\0';

       temp.home=(char*)malloc(20); 
       strcpy(temp.home, buffer);

       read>>buffer;
       len=strlen(buffer);
       if(buffer[len-1]=='\n')
       buffer[len-1]='\0';


       temp.cell=(char*)malloc(20); 
       strcpy(temp.cell, buffer); 

      friends[i].First_Name=(char*)malloc(MAXNAME);
      friends[i].Last_Name=(char*)malloc(MAXNAME);
      friends[i].home=(char*)malloc(MAXPHONE);
      friends[i].cell=(char*)malloc(MAXPHONE);


  //adds file content to the structure
      strcpy(friends[*counter].First_Name,temp.First_Name);
      strcpy(friends[*counter].Last_Name,temp.Last_Name);
      strcpy(friends[*counter].home,temp.home);
      strcpy(friends[*counter].cell,temp.cell);


     (*counter)++;
     i++; 

   }
   //closes file and frees memory
    read.close();
    free(temp.Last_Name);
    free(temp.First_Name);
    free(temp.home);
    free(temp.cell);
}
```

Comment: Can you give us the contents of the file?

Comment: The file is is simply `johnny smith` next line `3` next line `4`. The `<Home>` and `<Cell>` is printed after the file gets read into the class and is simply the way I have it formatted.

Comment: This: `while (!read.eof())` is always wrong.  Always.  What if an error occurs?   How do you catch it and stop reading?

Answer (score 8):

1. Don't use `!eof()`. It checks whether the *last* read failure was due to reaching the end of the file. It does not predict the future.
2. Don't use `malloc` in C++. If you do, check the return value for errors!
3. Don't use `operator>>` for `char *`. There's no size check so that's just asking for buffer overflows.
4. The `'\n'` check on buffer is useless. `operator>>` for strings stops at whitespace.
5. You're blindly `strcpy`ing a string of unknown length into `temp.home` of size 20. That's another buffer overflow.
6. ... I kind of stopped reading there. If you want to read stuff from a file but stop on eof/error, you can do something like this:

.

```
string a, b, c;
while (true) {
    if (!(in >> a)) break;
    if (!(in >> b)) break;
    if (!(in >> c)) break;
    do_stuff_with(a, b, c);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Do **not** use `eof()` to determine if you reached end of file. Instead, read what you want to read and **then** check if you successfully read the data. Obce reading failed you may use `eof()` to determine if the error is down to having reached the end of the file before producing an error report about a format error.

Since you mentioned that you read that using `!infile.eof()` is good practice: Can you point us at the source of this wrong information? This information need correction.

Comment: My post says that I read it was POOR practice, not that it was good practice.

Comment: Sorry, poor reading from my end. However, `if (infile.getline(buffer, n)) { ... }` should work just fine (although I'd recommend using `std::getline(in, str)` with a `std::string`.

Comment: what doest the `n` stand for in that `infile.getline`statement. forgive me for being a rookie lol.

Comment: The `n` is the maximum number of `char`s you can store in `buffer`. Assuming `buffer` is declared as `char buffer[17];` it is `17` or `sizeof(buffer`)`.

Comment: ok, thats what I thought, and thats what I have been trying when I used the getline. My issue is that when I use getline my output looks like thus `3 4` next line`<Home> johnny smith` next line `<Cell>johnny smith`. not only does it print out the name twice, but it obviously jacks up the formatting.

Comment: Well, `std::istream::getline()` certainly does work and doesn't "jacks up" anything when used correctly. Since you don't show the code producing this problem I can't tell where things go wrong. Judging from the code you wrote, I'd recommend *strongly* that you throw out all uses of `malloc()`, `strcpy(), and `free()` and rather using the class `std::string`. If this is a homework assignment and you are not supposed to use this class, create your own simple string class instead (using `new char[n]`, `delete[] p`, etc.).