# C++ Dynamic array of structs segmentation fault

Tags: c++, arrays

I am working on a program that reads data from a text file called "phonebook.txt" and displays it in terminal. It ask how many contacts the user wants to add. The user will input the number of contacts he/she wants and the program will output this along with the old contacts from "phonebook.txt" to "updated-phonebook.txt." Now I chose to use a dynamic array over a vector simply because I wanted to get a feel for how to handle memory allocation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream> 

#define nullptr 0;


struct Person
{
  std::string lName, fName, streetAddr, city, state, zip, phoneNum;
};

int main ()
{
  std::ofstream outFile;
  std::string dummy;
  int amount, total, count = 0;
  Person *contact;
  //set the pointer to 0 so its not pointing
  //to anything else in memory 
  contact = nullptr;
  std::ifstream inFile("/home/isemanthaj/My_Programs/Class_Programs/Assignment_3/phonebook/phonebook.txt",std::ios::in);
  if (!inFile)
    {
      std::cout << "File failed to open" << std::endl;
    }
  else

  outFile.open("updated_phonebook.txt", std::ios::out);

  std::cout << "How many contacts do you want to add?" << std::endl;
  std::cin >> amount;
  contact = new Person[amount];
   std::cout << "Contacts in the previous book \n" << std::endl;

   std::cin.ignore();

         while (inFile)
    {
      //dummy stores the contact number which is the first line
      // in the read file. I don't want to carry the number over
      // to the other updated_phonebook.txt file
      std::getline(inFile, dummy);
      std::getline(inFile, contact[count].lName);
      std::getline(inFile, contact[count].fName);
      std::getline(inFile, contact[count].streetAddr);
      std::getline(inFile, contact[count].city);
      std::getline(inFile, contact[count].state);
      std::getline(inFile, contact[count].zip);
      std::getline(inFile, contact[count].phoneNum);

      std::cout << contact[count].lName << std::endl;
      std::cout << contact[count].fName << std::endl;
      std::cout << contact[count].streetAddr << std::endl;
      std::cout << contact[count].city << std::endl;
      std::cout << contact[count].state << std::endl;
      std::cout << contact[count].zip << std::endl;
      std::cout << contact[count].phoneNum << std::endl;


      outFile << contact[count].lName << std::endl;
      outFile << contact[count].fName << std::endl;
      outFile << contact[count].streetAddr << std::endl;
      outFile << contact[count].city << std::endl;
      outFile << contact[count].state << std::endl;
      outFile << contact[count].zip << std::endl;
      outFile << contact[count].phoneNum << std::endl;
      count++;
    }
     // I know this is a little wacky here. 
     // I want the program to display the total amount of contacts
     // to the screen
     total = amount + count;

    for (int index = 0; index < total; index++)
     {

       std::cout << "Last name: ";
       std::getline(std::cin, contact[index].lName);
       std::cout << "First name: ";

       std::getline(std::cin, contact[index].fName);
       std::cout << "Street address: ";
       std::getline(std::cin, contact[index].streetAddr);

       std::cout << "City: ";
       std::getline(std::cin, contact[index].city);

       std::cout << "State: ";
       std::getline(std::cin, contact[index].state);

       std::cout << "Zip code: ";
       std::getline(std::cin, contact[index].zip);

       std::cout << "Phone number: ";
       std::getline(std::cin, contact[index].phoneNum);
       std::cout << std::endl;

       std::cout << "Contact: " << index + 1 << std::endl;
       std::cout << "Last name: " << contact[index].lName << std::endl;
       std::cout << "First name: " << contact[index].fName << std::endl;
       std::cout << "Street address: " << contact[index].streetAddr << std::endl;
       std::cout << "City: " << contact[index].city << std::endl;
       std::cout << "State: " << contact[index].state << std::endl;
       std::cout << "Zip code: " << contact[index].zip << std::endl;
       std::cout << "Phone number: " << contact[index].phoneNum << std::endl;
       std::cout << std::endl;
       outFile << "Last name: " << contact[index].lName << std::endl;
       outFile << "First name: " << contact[index].fName << std::endl;
       outFile << "Street address: " << contact[index].streetAddr << std::endl;
       outFile << "City: " << contact[index].city << std::endl;
       outFile << "State: " << contact[index].state << std::endl;
       outFile << "Zip code: " << contact[index].zip << std::endl;
       outFile << "Phone number: " << contact[index].phoneNum << std::endl;


     }

   inFile.close();
   outFile.close();
   delete [] contact;

return 0; 
}
```

I am trying to store the new contacts the user created and the old contacts from the read file in one dynamic array of structures. Am I getting this segmentation fault because I am using two different indexes "count" and "index" to store the contacts in the same dynamic array?

Comment: `#define nullptr 0;` why?

Comment: `#define nullptr 0` is bad. You have `NULL`. You're probably not `std::cin`'ing a valid `size_t`.

Comment: `while (inFile)` is an anti-pattern. Don't do error checking like that.

Comment: And needless to say, monolithic code is also an anti-pattern.

Comment: As far as I understand, you allocate an array of size 'amount' elements but then you try to read 'amount + count' elements from that array, which is out-of-bound.

Comment: Karoly Horvath Thats true. I thought putting it all in main would make it easier for you guys to see the problem. My bad.

Comment: I thought I had to set the pointer to null before allocating memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your segfault is happening because you are trying to access an out-of-bounds element of `contact` array. The size of `contact` is `amount`, and you are iterating it from 0 to `amount + count`. Obviously, `amount + count >= amount`, so sooner or later you will run out of bounds.

I would suggest you to use `std::vector` instead of a plain array. You will always be aware of it's size and will be able to iterate it safely.

If you want to keep the arrays, you will have to either reallocate `contact` after copying the contacts from the old file, to make it size equal to `total`, or make two separate arrays: one to hold the records from the old file with the size of `amount` elements, and another one for the newly-added contacts with the size of `count` elements.

As it is mentioned in the comments, your end-of-file check is wrong, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647/reading-from-text-file-until-eof-repeats-last-line) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13544245/reading-until-the-end-of-file-in-c) questions are relevant.

Comment: and he has no sync between the `eof` and the `amount` he is getting from user.

Comment: Thank you! I prefer vectors too. But I wanted to use a dynamic array as an example for myself to see how to how they work. I think making two separate arrays is a good idea. I will check the posts you referred me too.